# How to loop through JSON (with AngularJS) and put the results in a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using the latest AngularJS version (1.3.0-rc.5), I am retrieving a simple JSON object containing people's names. Example of the JSON object:

```
[{'id':1, 'name':'John'}, {'id':2, 'name':'Jane'}, {'id':3, 'name':'Pete'}]
```

I cannot figure out how to put all the names into an associative Javascript array. In my mind I want to create an empty Javascript array and loop through the JSON object, and using `.push()` in the loop to keep adding the names to the array. But I cannot get this working in AngularJS.

ps. I'll accept the answer that helps me out with this.

Comment: It looks simple. please create fiddle and show your problem.

Comment: 1.3.13 is the latest of angular 1.3 and there is also 1.4.0-beta.4  https://code.angularjs.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular is not meant to help you with this, Angular is meant for other parts of the application (UI for instance).
If you want to do this, in JS it's simple:

```
var list = [{'id':1, 'name':'John'}, {'id':2, 'name':'Jane'}, {'id':3, 'name':'Pete'}]
var names = []
for(var idx in list) {
  names.push(list[idx]['name'])
}
```

You also mentioned an associative array, in JS you have objects, which work similarly, but I don't understand how you want to use them... what is the index for that associative array? The name? If that's the case, then what is the value? is it the ID?
If so, you could do something like this:

```
var list = [{'id':1, 'name':'John'}, {'id':2, 'name':'Jane'}, {'id':3, 'name':'Pete'}]
var names = {} //object literal
for(var idx in list) {
  names[list[idx]['name']] = list[idx]['id']
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in pure javascript

```
var arr = [{'id':1, 'name':'John'}, {'id':2, 'name':'Jane'}, {'id':3, 'name':'Pete'}];
var nameArr =[];
arr.forEach(
function(elem){ 
  nameArr.push(elem.name);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map(..)` on your array object.

```
var obj = [{'id':1, 'name':'John'}, {'id':2, 'name':'Jane'}, {'id':3, 'name':'Pete'}];
var result = obj.map(function (x) {return x["name"]; });
//["John", "Jane", "Pete"]
```

Comment: Man, map is cross browser already? How did I not know this!? Thanks, you brightened my day!

Comment: I would expect it to work on all modern browsers. I do not know about Internet Explorer, though.

Comment: Wait, I take that back. Internet Explorer doesn't fit my definition of modern. :P

Comment: Well according to this: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.map even IE supports it.

Answer (score -2):

Use angular.fromJson() function to solve this.